# Join Table and Select Highest Date Value

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, max

Here is the query that I run

```
SELECT cl.cl_id, cc_rego, cc_model, cl_dateIn, cl_dateOut
FROM courtesycar cc LEFT JOIN courtesyloan cl
ON cc.cc_id = cl.cc_id
```

Results:

> 1. **1**   NXI955  Prado   *2013-10-24 11:48:38*    NULL
> 2. **2**   RJI603  Avalon  *2013-10-24 11:48:42*    2013-10-24 11:54:18
> 3. **3**   RJI603  Avalon  *2013-10-24 12:01:40*    NULL

The results that I wanted are to group by the `cc_rego` values and print the most recent `cl_dateIn` value. (Only Display Rows 1,3)

I've tried to use MAX on the date and group by clause, but it combines rows, 2 & 3 together showing both the highest value of `dateIn` and `dateOut`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the problem.

Instead of using left join, I added a condition in the where clause which embeds to MAX of the dateIn

```
SELECT cll.cl_id, cc.cc_id, cc_rego, cc_model, cll.cl_dateIn, cll.cl_dateOut
FROM courtesycar cc, courtesyloan cll
WHERE cl_dateIn = ( 
  SELECT  MAX( cl.cl_dateIn )
  FROM courtesyloan cl
  WHERE cl.cc_id = cc.cc_id )
AND cc.cc_id = cll.cc_id
```